# Grep with variable cause file with data empty

Tags: bash, shell, grep

When i use this command in a script:

```
grep -A 12 -B 37 "1000221411" /home/ashb/20181007/soap_nohup_20181007_0*.log | awk '{$1=""}1' > abcdef.txt
```

But when i try to put variables to find more id in log files:

```
grep -A 12 -B 37 ${b} /home/ashb/20181007/soap_nohup_20181007_0*.log | awk '{$1=""}1' > abcdef.txt
```

Then the abcdef.txt turn out to be empty file.
I try to `echo ${b}` and it is in my path.
how can i fix that?
The input of `${b}`:

```
1000221411
1000248725
1000287875
1000296552
```

Comment: "When i use this" then what?

Comment: Welcome to SO @Blake Ash, it is always recommended to show us sample of input and sample of expected output in your post in code tags, so kindly do so.

Comment: @Yunnosch the first command, then the abcdef.txt file have data. but when i execute the second one, that file become empty

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 
This is the sample of ${b}:
1000221411
1000248725
1000287875
1000296552
1000378719
1001098309
1006130491
1008508371
1036754712
When i grep it in log file manually and pipe into abcdef.txt file, it succeed. 
But when i put variable in the command, the txt file turn empty

Comment: @BlakeAsh, kindly post samples in your post NOT in comments, comments are not meant for that. Kindly use code tags for same too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash: space in variable value later used as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249821/bash-space-in-variable-value-later-used-as-parameter)

Comment: Replace `$b` in your command with the contents of the variable. `grep -A 12 -B 37 1000221411 1000248725 1000287875...` That's not going to work well, is it?

Comment: @miken32 yeah, if i point out, it works correctly. Put when i put variable in the command, the file turn into empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat file
foo
1000221411
bar
1000296552

$ echo "$b"
1000221411
1000248725
1000287875
1000296552

$ grep -f <(echo "$b") file
1000221411
1000296552
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though `${b}` is *meant* to be an array, since it contains **9** numbers.  The trouble with the code above is:

1. `${b}` is unquoted, so `grep` gets **8** parameters too many.
2. If `${b}` were quoted, `grep` would only find **9** numbers in the same order.  But `grep` would not find anything in a file with only *one* of those numbers.